# Pagination of pages

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, jinja2

I have been looking for an answer for a long time how to implement pagination on the site, I use only Python and its frameworks.
Is it even possible to do this? If so, how to use the jinja template engine to create a new page automatically with ten or more discussion elements. If there is no python solution, then I would really like to know how to implement it through js along with html in order to at least understand the mechanics.

html

```
            {% for discussion in discussions_json %}
            <a style="font-size: 19px; margin-right: auto; width: 88%; color:white; text-decoration:none; " href="/community/discussion/{{ discussion.id }}">{{ discussion.title }}</a> <span style="font-size: 25px; float: right; color: #0abab5;">{{ discussion.date.strftime("%H:%M | %d.%m.%Y") }}</span>
              <p style="font-size: 19px; margin-right: auto; width: 88%; color: red;">@{{ discussion.username }}</p>
              <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="32" height="32" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-chat-dots-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                <path d="M16 8c0 3.866-3.582 7-8 7a9 9 0 0 1-2.347-.306c-.584.296-1.925.864-4.181 1.234-.2.032-.352-.176-.273-.362.354-.836.674-1.95.77-2.966C.744 11.37 0 9.76 0 8c0-3.866 3.582-7 8-7s8 3.134 8 7M5 8a1 1 0 1 0-2 0 1 1 0 0 0 2 0m4 0a1 1 0 1 0-2 0 1 1 0 0 0 2 0m3 1a1 1 0 1 0 0-2 1 1 0 0 0 0 2"/>
              </svg>
              <span> {{ discussion.answer_count }}</span>
              <hr />
            {% endfor %}
```

python

```
@blueprint.route('/community')
def community_page():
    discussions_json = []
    discussions_list = Discussions.query.filter(Discussions.title.isnot(None)).order_by(Discussions.date.desc()).all()
    for discussion in discussions_list:
        discussions_json.append(
            {
                "id": discussion.id,
                "title": discussion.title,
                "text": discussion.text,
                "date": discussion.date,
                "username": User.query.filter_by(id=discussion.autor).first().username,
                "answer_count": discussion.answer_count()
            }
        )

    return render_template("community.html", discussions_json=discussions_json)
```

Comment: There are some resources about this problem on the web. I found [this](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-paginate/) and [that](https://betterprogramming.pub/simple-flask-pagination-example-4190b12c2e2e)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following example shows you how you can implement pagination with the Flask-SQLAlchemy legacy API you are using.

Instead of a request with a final `all()`, the command [`paginate(page=None, per_page=None, error_out=True, max_per_page=None)`](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/api/#flask_sqlalchemy.BaseQuery.paginate) is used. It is then possible to add navigation for all available pages in the template. In the example this is achieved using a [jinja macro](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#macros). The database entries that were previously available directly are now accessible via the `items` attribute of the [pagination object](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/api/#flask_sqlalchemy.Pagination).

```py
from flask import (
    Flask, 
    render_template, 
    request
)
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy 
from sqlalchemy import func
from sqlalchemy.ext.associationproxy import association_proxy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_mapping(
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI='sqlite:///example.db'
)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False, unique=True)
    # ...
    discussions = db.relationship('Discussion', backref='author')

class Discussion(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String)
    text = db.Column(db.Text)
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime,
        nullable=False, 
        server_default=func.now())
    author_id = db.Column(db.Integer,
        db.ForeignKey('user.id'),
        nullable=False)
    # ...
    username = association_proxy('author', 'username')

with app.app_context():
    db.drop_all()
    db.create_all()

    user = User(username='dummy')
    db.session.add(user)

    discussions = [
        Discussion(
            author=user, 
            title=f'Title-{i}', 
            text='Your text here!'
        )
        for i in range(1, 21)
    ]
    db.session.add_all(discussions)
    db.session.commit()

@app.route('/community')
def community_page():
    per_page = 5
    page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)
    discussions = Discussion.query\
        .filter(Discussion.title.isnot(None))\
        .order_by(Discussion.date.desc())\
        .paginate(page=page, per_page=per_page)
    return render_template('community.html', **locals())

# ...
```

```
{% macro render_pagination(pagination, endpoint) %}
  <div class=pagination>
  {%- for page in pagination.iter_pages() %}
    {% if page %}
      {% if page != pagination.page %}
        <a href="{{ url_for(endpoint, page=page) }}">{{ page }}</a>
      {% else %}
        <strong>{{ page }}</strong>
      {% endif %}
    {% else %}
      <span class=ellipsis>…</span>
    {% endif %}
  {%- endfor %}
  </div>
{% endmacro %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Community</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% for discussion in discussions.items -%}
        <a href="/community/discussion/{{ discussion.id }}">{{ discussion.title }}</a>
        <span>{{ discussion.date.strftime("%H:%M | %d.%m.%Y") }}</span>
        <p>@{{ discussion.username }}</p>
        <hr />
    {% endfor -%}
    {{ render_pagination(discussions, request.endpoint) }}
</body>
</html>
```

If you are interested in how pagination can be implemented with the latest query variant, I recommend [this](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-ix-pagination) article.